# Как PDO в PHP находит базу данных?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Работаю с PDO в PHP, разбирал чужой код и наткнулся на такую строку подключения PDO:

```
return new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDb;charset=utf8", $user, $password, array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
));
```

И у меня появился вопрос. Собственно, а где путь до базы данных? Как он ее находит? А если у меня база данных в Access и лежит отдельным файликом?

Comment: База данных Access это не mysql.

Comment: *А если у меня база данных в Access и лежит отдельным файликом?* .. то в строке подключения будут точные диск:путь:имя - или никакой любви с базой не случится.

Comment: первый параметр ровно этим и занимается - рассказывает пдошечке, где найти базу. называется DSN

Comment: mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDb;charset=utf8
mysql - будет искать по умолчанию на порте 3306 и на хосте localhost. Т.е. по адресу localhost:3306. Например если ты изменишь настройки mysql по умолчанию и изменишь порт, то уже соеденения не будет. Нужно будет прописывать порт в pdo руками.